# AngularJs: Respnd to Http post from third part server

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an app using AngularJS and NodeJS. Being new to both I am struggling a bit.

My app is communicating with payment gateway to facilitate payments. Flow goes like MyApp-->Payment Gateway --> MyApp. I am able to send the request to payment gateway. **Problem** is I am not able to figure out how I will handle response that is coming from payment gateway. Payment Gateway is sending some data in the post request. I need to process this data before showing results of transaction to user.

Technically speaking I know what needs to be done. Like Step 1) Giving a return URL to Payment Gateway to which Post request will be sent. Step2) This HTML URL of my application will send data received from payment gateway to server side for processing. Step3) Based on processed results I will show transaction result to user.

Where I am struggling is show to achieve this using AngularJS and Nodejs. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to easily send and get data from server.

Comment: Thanks for response. $http can send GET and POST request within our application or probably to a third party application.Here I am talking about accepting data in http post from third party system