# How to accept http posted data from payment gateway server in angularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

The payment gateway request contains many parameters along with ReturnURL,

depending upon payment,  either successful or not the status code and error code etc from payment gateway are posted with ReturnURL,

when this posted data are retrieved in web API controller then it gives me result,

Snippet: (Its a sample code not a full code)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PGResponse()
        {
            string strPGResponse = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["msg"];
            string strMerchantCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["tpsl_mrct_cd"];
            return Response(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

But when I'd try to get this posted data from payment gateway in angular then I am not sure how can i achieve the same

You please refer same question that is unanswered yet on following link.
[AngularJs: Respnd to Http post from third part server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999403/angularjs-respnd-to-http-post-from-third-part-server)

So please help upon same issue.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT ---------------------

1) I'd call the 
submitCart(id, total, returnURL, currentURL) 
from angularJS.

2) This call reaches to  this method in web api
public async Task SubmitCart(long id, long total, string returnurl, string currenturl)

3) After that Payment request made in above method and browser redirect to payment gateway page.

4) After providing information to gateway like card id, bank name etc then depending upon request,  gateway give me a posted form data 
by using ReturnURL.
like

http://localhost:3321/Cart/PGResponse

5) I'd get those response by using this method

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PGResponse()
    {
        string strPGResponse = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["msg"];
        string strMerchantCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["tpsl_mrct_cd"];


        List<Cart> CartList = await _cartService.GetByUserBasicID(Convert.ToInt64(custid));

        return Response(HttpStatusCode.OK, CartList);  // This is my private function
    }
```

6) I'd successfuly get Response from gateway and i want to show gateway response msg to user along with it's cart data say CartList.
so how can I display thank you page with gateway response along with cart data.. in my angular app.

Comment: is your web application redirects to payment gateway?

Comment: yes it redirect to payment gateway and then it redirect to our website which I redirecting to WEB API action and process [something] which user purchased but after that I want to show the thank you page with some data on that page.

Comment: display just a thank you page? Or do you want initialize your angular app after redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass your API's url as the redirect url. Because API can only return data not your application.

So, I suggest you to create a MVC controller not API controller to receive data from the payment gateway.

```
public ActionResult PGResponse()
{
        string strPGResponse = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["msg"];
        string strMerchantCode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["tpsl_mrct_cd"];


        List<Cart> CartList = await _cartService.GetByUserBasicID(Convert.ToInt64(custid));
        if(success){
             return View("success.html");
        }
        return View("failed.html");  // return your angular application page.
}
```

`success.html` and `failed.html` are pages used to display status of payment.

**Still you are not come back to your angular application.**

User should be redirect to your angular application from the status page. You can write a simple jquery code to redirect to your application after a minute or some time.

Hope this will help you.

Feel free to ask any doubt on this.

Comment: We have 2 application
1. Angular App (just angular no MVC)
2. WEB API  and both are hosted on different sub domains.
Returning view is not possible because angular app is in another subdoamain and we have to pass cart list with thank you page.

Comment: @MayurLohite. The problem is that `angularJs` is only a client side script. So, It is impossible to get data from a post request by using angular.

Comment: @MayurLohite, So we need to use API or MVC to get request data from the payment gateway. As API is hosted in another subdomain we can't involk our angular app.

Comment: @MayurLohite, another option that, open payment gateway in a new tab or window. So, we don't want to redirect user from payment gateway. Payment details will be manipulated independently.

Comment: @MayurLohite, If you want to see an example for this, please check `google adword`. They allow user to make payment in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you will check for that.